# How can we rank rows of a matrix based on the mean of each column?

Tags: r

I want to rank each row of my data based on the mean of each column
Here you can find an example data

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c69

I calculate the mean of row and the mean of each row and each column by

```
C <- colMeans(data, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)
R <- rowMeans(data, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)
```

Then I divide each row mean by each column mean and somehow rank them. Is there any idea?

Comment: what do you mean with it is not clear? I wrote I want to rank each row of the attached data based on their mean values

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ example data set, and also show us the desired result, and the code you have tried yourself. You have to be more specific than "somehow rank them", otherwise the question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: @Nemo It is not clear to me that is what I said.  If you had showed a small example data and desired data, that would be more clear.  You mentioned to divide each row mean by each column mean and somehow rank them. rank what?

Comment: @ Henrik Do you read my question? I have provided the data, I have provided the first step of how i calculated the mean. if i knew how to rank them, then I would not ask here! Please Please if you cannot help, don't put comment for nothing

Comment: Thanks @akrun  now I try to modify the question

Comment: @Nemo I think you need to get the rowMeans extend to each row and likewise, colMeans extend to each element of column and then divide one by the other and rank.

Comment: @akrun That is a good idea,

Comment: "Please Please if you cannot help, don't put comment for nothing". I did not comment for nothing. I asked for clarification to be able to help you, just as @akrun did. Ranting is not the way to attract help on SO.

Comment: @Nemo Your first column is character (`probes`).  I guess you did subset the data

Comment: @akrun You can ignore the first column because those correspond to the name of each row so that I can find them after they are ranked , you might use the function called  " as.matrix " or remove the first column by data <- data(c(-1))

Comment: @Nemo I added a solution, but as I mentioned earlier, I am not completely sure about the expected result

Comment: @akrun thanks for your time, can you please comment on the functions so that I can follow what you did? can you also please mention how to find which row is in a higher list than others ?

Comment: @Nemo I added some explanation.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data to your question? The link on github may go down, rendering this question next to obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we read the dataset, (`read.table('Nemo.txt'....)`), remove the first character column (`data2 <- data[,-1]`), get the row means and column means and extend it to the "row/column" (`rowMeans(...)[row(data)]`), divide and create a matrix "m1". If we need to get the "ranks" of rows for each column in "m1", use `mutate_each` from `dplyr`.

```
data <- read.table('Nemo.txt', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data2 <- data[,-1]
m1 <- rowMeans(data2, na.rm=FALSE, dims=1)[row(data2)]/colMeans(data2,
          na.rm=FALSE, dims=1)[col(data2)]
dim(m1) <- dim(data2)
library(dplyr)
d1 <- as.data.frame(m1) 
d1 %>% 
   mutate_each(funs(rank(., ties.method='min')))
```

But, suppose we need to get the aggregate `rank` of each row, (not sure if this is what you want), perhaps we can get the row means of "m1" and rank it.

```
rnk <- rank(rowMeans(m1)) 
head(rnk)
#[1] 1234 1557 1052 1176  575  290
```

Then rank the original data based on rnk as follows:

```
rankeddata <- data[rnk,]
```

Comment: I got the following error :      rank(rowMeans(m1))
Error in rowMeans(m1) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: @Nemo I am not getting the error.  I tried it on a fresh R session without loading any package.  Not getting any errors.  I use R 3.1.2.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer but can you please now incorporate the first row we remove to find which rows are in top of the list and which rows are in down ?

Comment: @Nemo We didn't remove any rows, but only the first column.

Comment: @Nemo If you need to order the dataset based on `rnk`, then `data[rnk,]`

Comment: Try `rnk <- rank(m1)`.

Comment: @Elin Thanks, but it seems to me that the OP wanted the rank in a specific way

Comment: So you have calculated m1 as the rowMeans() but now you are taking the rowMeans(m1), so that is going to be a scalar right?

Comment: @Elin That was one thing I did.  To be honest, I didn't quite understand what the OP wanted.

Comment: I mean it's an array with 1 dimension. Yeah I know, I was just commenting based on the error message.  I'm not sure quite what the OP is trying to get at all.